# Comparing timestamp to current_timestamp not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp, compare

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.user_id
              , c.status
              , c.content_id
              , m.meta_key
              , m.meta_value
              , m.user_id
              , c.timestamp 
           FROM wp_grassblade_completions c
           JOIN wp_usermeta m
             ON m.user_id = c.user_id 
          WHERE wp_grassblade_completions.timestamp >= '2017/06/01 00:00' AND meta_key IN ('mepr_full_name', 'mepr_address', 'mepr_city', 'mepr_state', 'mepr_zip_code', 'mepr_home_phone_with_area_code',   'mepr_drivers_license_or_id', 'mepr_id_state', 'mepr_LAst_four_of_social_security_number', 'mepr_date_of_birth_mmddyyyy', 'mepr_sex_mf', 'mepr_height', 'mepr_weight') order 
             BY content_id
              , m.user_id
```

Trying to compare the timestamp on a record and see if it is older than a date, current_timestamp -7 or some other method of finding records not older than a week.  When I run the above query, all records are returned.  I've searched the forum and tried several answers, to no avail.

The datatype that is stored in the timestamp column is actually TIMESTAMP.  Not sure where to go from here....

Comment: The relevant code is here:
WHERE wp_grassblade_completions.timestamp >= '2017/06/01'

Comment: The assiduous use of parentheses would help here, although IN() is generally easier to read.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'm sure the original edit made your eyes bleed! lol.  I put this together a piece at a time and I didn't go back and fix the syntax.

Comment: It's not simply a question of syntax. The logic of the original query was (almost certainly flawed and) fundamentally different from what you have now. Still, my second comment was more important than my first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure of the data you currently have in your DB, but assuming this format

`2017/10/01 00:00`

Try this

```
 WHERE wp_grassblade_completions.timestamp >= (NOW()- INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Instead of this

```
 WHERE wp_grassblade_completions.timestamp >= '2017/06/01 00:00'
```